# Book reading question Conformal Field Theory and topology by Toshitake Kohno page 2

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Conformal Field Theory and topology by Toshitake Kohno.

> Given a sympathetic form $\omega$, we have a one-to-one correspondence between 1-forms on M and smooth vector fields on $M$ in the following way. Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on $M$. We define a 1-form $\varphi=i(X)\omega$ by

> $\varphi(Y)=\omega(X,Y)$

> for a smooth vector field $Y$ on $M$. The above correspondence

> $X\mapsto i(X)\omega$

> gives an isomorphism between the vector space of 1-forms on M and the vector space of smooth vector fields on $M$. Let $f$ be a smooth function on $M$. We define a vector field $X_f$ by

> $i(X_f)\omega=df$

> We call $X_f$ the Hamiltonian vector field for $f$.

Could you explain what the above text meant, please? More specifically, for example, What does the notation $i(X)\omega$ meant? Wasn't the vector field $X$ defined as $X^a\partial_{a}$? so how exactly does the correspondence and $df$ explain each other?